# A letter to/for Jason?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, to-for

Suppose Jason were at home and a mail carrier came to his front door with a letter addressed to Jason. Which of the following is correct?

1. It was a letter ***for*** Jason.
2. It was a letter ***to*** Jason.

Answer (score 2):

What a great question! The answer is (1) A letter *for* Jason.

One writes a letter *to* someone. Having been written, the letter is a letter *for* that person. So the mail carrier would be at the door with a letter to Jason only if s/he had written said letter.

To take another example: The person who used to live in my apartment has moved to a different apartment down the hall. However, she has not updated her address with the post office. Consequently, a lot of letters *for* her end up being delivered to my place. I am considering writing a letter *to* her asking her to fill out a change-of-address form at the post office.

The difference lies in the role played by the person getting the letter. A letter is written *to* an addressee. It is intended *for* a recipient. For the person writing the letter, Jason is the addressee, so the person is writing *to* Jason. For anybody else involved in getting the letter into Jason's hand, Jason is the recipient, so from this point of view, the letter is *for* Jason.

Comment: Upvoted for good comparison.

Comment: No, either is acceptable and idiomatic. 'To' emphasises the addressee, 'for' the benefactive aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable; there is little difference in meaning.

Comment: @tchrist Is it acceptable to edit according to personal style and preference rather than correcting mistakes or editing for clarity? There was nothing wrong with my original sentence, I am quite capable of deciding whether to use a comma or semicolon. Please don't quote me any semicolon rules.

Comment: What you wrote was a comma splice, I won’t quote you semicolon rules, the correction improved the site.

Comment: @Mynamite: It pisses me off too when someone decides that their understanding of grammar is better than mine, but sometimes, you know, it is, & I've been teaching grammar at the university level for 40 years. I agree with tchrist in this case. Your comma splice was ungrammatical; his edit improved your answer; and, yes, it is acceptable to edit answers when they're grammatically incorrect. I would have used a colon or a period, but there's nothing wrong with a semicolon. Comma splices are okay only for dialogue. I don't like them even there, but speech is often ungrammatical.

Comment: Speaking as someone who quite often types comma splices in haste, I have to agree with tchrist's edit too. I think a degree of haste resulting in typos is reasonable with the way this site works, and it would be unreasonable to comment criticising someone for such a mistake, but tchrist is certainly welcome to correct any comma splices he might find in my answers, and I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "It is a letter for Jason". The preposition used in these two sentences doesn't **necessarily** change the meaning.

The mail carrier most likely doesn't know what's in the letter, and neither do I; therefore, for us, both of these sentences are essentially the same.

Even though the letter is addressed **to** Jason, it might contain something intended **for** someone else. In this case, the preposition used changes the meaning based on a knowledge of the content of the letter.

Comment: Suppose letter is a postcard and it contains nothing except for words written on it. Would you prefer 'to' over 'for' in this case?

Answer (score 0):

They would be used in different contexts. *It was a letter for Jason* might be given as a reply to the question *What was that you put on the table this morning?*  *It was a letter to Jason*, however, might answer the question *What upset you last night?* (Those examples illustrate the point, but in practice they would probably be framed slightly differently.)

Answer (score -1):

I was advised that if you refer to people of higher authority such as politicians, CEO etc,  FOR should be used as a sign of courtesy.

Comment: What was the source of this advice?